find the average of a group of index values in a pandas data frame based on proximity to other values
Column A has a range of numbers. I'd like to compare each number to every other number in Column A. I'd like an average for each number of all the values that have a difference of less than/ equal to 2. The desired output would be in column B. The is the solution that worked in Excel:
=AVERAGE(IF(INDEX(ABS($A$1:$A$5-TRANSPOSE($A$1:$A$5)),,ROW(B1))<2,$A$1:$A$5))

However, now I'm trying to learn Python and would like to move the solution there.  Any help would be much appreciated.


Desiring an output is not enough. You will need to write some code to actually obtain the result.

please don't sent image for your df would be nice to write it here. Also, please provide us what u have done and what was wrong so we can help that

a = np.array([4798,4802,4803,4805,4809])
a - np.nanmean(np.where(abs(b := a - a[:,None]) <= 2, b, np.nan), 0)

array([4798.        , 4802.5       , 4803.33333333, 4804.        ,
       4809.        ])

